# Moving from BeautifulSoup to Scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am learning BeautifulSoup right now and I need to switch to Scrapy as I will need more powerful features later on such as form interaction etc.

Would the correct strategy be to port my BeautifulSoup script to scrapy or to somehow integrate the BeautifulSoup code within scrapy?

**Beautiful Soup Code**

```
 #Imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd 

html = """<div class="box1">
<table class="table1">
<tr><td class="label">Item1</td><td>Value1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item2</td><td>Value2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item3</td><td>Value3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="label">Item4</td><td>Value4</td></tr>
</table>
</div>"""

#Grab our page as text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

#Target what we want
div = soup.find("div", class_="box1")

#Filter what we want
columns = []
for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
    columns.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all("td")])

#Transpose our columns
columns = list(zip(*columns))   

#Output our results to Excel
df = pd.DataFrame(columns)   
df.to_csv('index.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Check out [this link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-scrapy-with-beautifulsoup) to get a solid idea.

Comment: @SIM Thanks for the link, it works very well, you should put that in an answer below.

Comment: It's okay. Thanks.